# Fork() Command in Linux C coding

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, child-process

I am having a hard time understanding how many processes I end up with using the fork() command. If I start out with a variable pid_t pid; and the call fork() I will the have a child and a parent process.

Now what if I call fork immediately after that first fork(). Do I know have 3 or 4 processes? Like is this fork called on both the parent and child, or just the child? So does the child process fork() another child process therefore creating 3 processes? Or is fork called on both the parent and child, so now the parent will have a child that has a child of its own and the parent now has a second child process?

If fork is called again a third time do all 3 or 4 processes get children? Only the latest child?

Depending on how fork() works how many processes are created when you call fork() 3 times? I am stuck between 4,6, or 8.

[Here is the Linux C coding. How many processes will run when this program iis executed, including itself. Every process must terminate using the return(0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT3Pd.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please, post code as *code* and not a picture.

Comment: So posting the code as image was easier than following site-rules and post it as text with simple copy/paste??

Comment: Note that `fork()` is a function or system call, not a command.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `fork()`, the process is duplicated, and both the parent and child continue executing all the code in the program. If you want them to act differently, you need to check the return value -- it returns `0` in the child, the child's PID in the parent. If you don't have any code that conditionalizes on this, they'll both execute everything the same. So if it calls `fork()` again, this will happen in both the parent and child, and you end up with 4 processes: the original parent, two children, and one grandchild. And the third `fork()` results in 8 processes.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out after realizing both parent and child are getting a new process each time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is 8, would each fork() just double the number of processes since there is no if statement specifying that only the parent/ child does the forking.